# Travel literature about cycling along the Rhine

Tags: recommendations, bicycles, guidebooks, rhine, literature

I'm looking for traveling literature that covers the topic of cycling along the Rhine river. There are a lot of books, but I couldn't find any that covers all my needs:

- It should be written in English and/or German
- It should be specifically about cycling
- It should cover the whole Rhine river from Lago Toma to Rotterdam and not just parts of it. I also do not want multiple volumes.
- It should be as cheap as possible.
- It shouldn't be heavy.
- It should also contain some hints about sights in the immediate perimeter of the Rhine.

Comment: So you want a very thin book on a 1200 km river and it immediate perimeter covering 4 countries? Isn't that under estimating the beauty and richness of that river?

Comment: And preferably for free ....

Comment: As cheap as possible does not mean for free. And it should be as thin/light as possible, since I want to carry it with me. I know that I won't get a 100 pages book, but I just don't want a 2000 pages book.

Comment: Would a kindle work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, there is no such a book. In [amazon.de](http://www.amazon.de) and [rhinecycleroute.eu](http://www.rhinecycleroute.eu/services-1?set_language=en) there some books about this cycle route. I think the best choice are the 3 books **Bikeline Radtourenbuch, Rhein-Radweg**. Each book costs about 13 EUR, the size is about 22,8 x 12,1 x 1,5 cm, and the weight about 350g.
As I already said, it's not what you want but there is nothing better.

Answer (score 4):

On [Everytrail](http://www.everytrail.com/view_trip.php?trip_id=717375) there is one person who set out a route. (like @Dirty-flow) He mentions [Rhein-Radweg 1](http://www.esterbauer.com/db_rtb_detail.php?buecher_code=RHE1), [Rhein-Radweg 2](http://www.esterbauer.com/db_rtb_detail.php?buecher_code=RHE2) and [Rhein-Radwg 3](http://www.esterbauer.com/db_rtb_detail.php?buecher_code=RHE3).

If you are in to apps, I would recommend the Everytrail app, as an alternative to a set of books

Comment: These are the same books as in my answer

Comment: Ok, didn't notice, but edited accordingly